# Python C API return more than one value / object without building a tuple

Tags: python, c

I got the following problem. I have written a C-Extension to Python(2.7 / 3.2) to interface a self written software library. Unfortunately I need to return two values from the function where the last one is optional. In Python I tried

```
def func(x,y): 
    return x+y, x-y

test = func(13,4)
```

but `test` is a tuple. If I write

```
test1,test2 = func(13,4)
```

I got both values separated. Is there a possibility to return only one value without unpacking the tuple, i.e. the second(,.. third, ..fourth) value gets neglected?

And if such a solution existst, how does it look for the C-API? Because

```
return Py_BuildValue("ii",x+y,x-y);
```

results in a tuple as well.

Comment: What version of python are you using? If I run your first snippet I do *not* get a single value, I get a 2-tuple as expected (and, IMO, is only sane--there are enough issues with not knowing return types in loosely typed languages without the return types changing depending on the call site!)

Comment: I reformulated the problem a bit more to point out the problem much better.

Comment: I see! I presume `test, _ = func(...)` isn't acceptable? I don't think this is something you're going to be able to do without a little syntactic overhead, unfortunately.

Comment: Addingg the addition dummy result `_` will be an option, but I am interested in a "more elegant" way.

Comment: Append a `[0]` after the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not special about the C API; this and the Python side behave consistently.

A tuple returned from a function can

- be unpacked, if its length is constant: `a, _ = f()`
- in 3.x, be unpacked, even if its length is not constant: `a, *_ = f()`
- be iterated over, but that is not useful here
- be indexed: `a = f()[0]`.